# How do you Highlight items in recylerview in android

Tags: android, highlight

I want to highlight items in recylerview on long press and I am able to do a part of that. The problem is that when I scroll in recylerview those items lose their highlighted state and when you click them after scrolling the `selectList` reduces in size as it should. The only problem is that how do I keep their state after scrolling?

Here is implementation in adapter class

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>  {
    private Context mContext;
    public static List<ItemFiles> itemFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    Activity activity;
    public  List<ItemFiles> selectList = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean isModeEnabled = false;

    public MyAdapter(Activity activity,List<ItemFiles> itemFiles,Context mContext) {
        this.activity = activity;
        MyAdapter.itemFiles = itemFiles;
        this.mContext = mContext;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }
    
      public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int
                position) {
       holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
           if (!isModeEnabled) {
              ActionMode d = new ActionMode.Callback() {
               @Override
               public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mode_menu,menu);
    
                return true;
        }
              @Override
              public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                 isActionModeEnabled = true;
                 ClickItem(holder);
               }
          });
                   return true;
              }
    
     holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   if (isActionModeEnabled) {
                        ClickItem(holder);
                   }
    
     public void ClickItem(MyViewHolder holder) {
            isSelectMode = true;
    
        ItemFiles s = itemFiles.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        if (holder.checkbox.getVisibility() == View.GONE && !selectList.contains(s)){
            selectList.add(s);
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    
        } else {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            selectList.remove(s);
        }
    }
    
    
       public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
           ImageView thm_img;
           TextView tv;
            public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                thm_img= itemView.findViewById(R.id.thm_img);
                tv= itemView.findViewById(R.id.vname);
            }
    }
```

This is xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/th_img"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/download"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"> 
   
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vname"     
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    </TextView>
   
  
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is xml of activity class for the recylerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".Fragment">

         <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
         </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
 
         <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:id="@+id/filesRV"/>
 
      </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Model class is

```
public class ItemFiles {
    public String id;
    public String path;
    public String title;
    public String fileName;
    public String size;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) { this.size = size; }

    public ItemFiles(String id, String path, String title, String fileName, String size) {
        this.id = id;
        this.path = path;
        this.title = title;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.size = size;
    }

}
```

Comment: You will have to save the selected state in the ItemFiles model. Then in the onLongClick save the new state of the item, and finally in the onBindViewHolder check for that state of the item and set the desired color if is true for example.

Comment: Could you explain with some code that would be of great help?

Comment: Please, add the full adapter code and the model code so it will be more easy.

Comment: I have added both adapter and model code.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to admit but the things you are experiencing is how it is supposed to be.

When Google created RecyclerView, they wanted it to have a Data-Driven-UI pattern, meaning that the UI is stateful. [What is state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455433/what-is-ui-state)

So by definition of stateful, you have to place every stateful data on the Model, in this case, the long press state.

Try copy-paste code below:

First, Add the long press state to the model:

```
public class ItemFiles {
  public String id;
  public String path;
  public String title;
  public String fileName;
  public String size;
  public boolean isLongPressed //long press state
  
  //add getters and setters
 
  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  ...
```

Second, when a user does a longpress, change the value of the model

```
 public void ClickItem(MyViewHolder holder) {
        isSelectMode = true;
        //Send your model to your viewholder so that you can reference the original model
        //s.setIsLongPressed(true) <-- I have used the code that you provided.
 ...
```

Third, make sure to make UI changes to show Highlight in `onBindViewHolder` based on your state value.

```
//A. In your viewholder class, make a method to receieve longPressState value.
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     ImageView thm_img;
     TextView tv;
     public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
         super(itemView);
         thm_img= itemView.findViewById(R.id.thm_img);
         tv= itemView.findViewById(R.id.vname);
    }
    
    public void setHightLightState(boolean isHighlighted) {
        if (isHighlighted) {
          //make highlight UI changes 
        } else {
          //make NON-highlight UI changes 
        }
    }
}


//B. Then, in your adapter, inside onBindViewHolder, call the new method above from the given holder.
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) { 
    holder.setHightLightState(/* pass in value from getIsLongPressed() */)
 }
```

Fourth, do not forget to refresh your recyclerview to reflect its changes, since its data has changed. You can use `notifyItemChanged(int position)` to update a single item or use `notifydatasetchanged` to update all items.

Lastly, do NOT forget to reset your longpress state in the model when user is finshed with longpress. Or else, the longpress state will be kept recycled, which is a common mistake when using RecyclerView.

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Could you explain with code how to add getters and setter of isLongPressed(); The problem is that ItemFiles itemFiles = new ItemFiles(id,path,title,fileName,size,isLongPressed); all require string but isLongPressed is booean and also how to reset the longpress state in the model?

Comment: I have used ItemFiles s = itemFiles.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()); in ClickItem() and set s.setIsLongPressed(true) in if block and set to false in else but it is still giving the same result.

Comment: @aab Sorry I was away for a while. Yup, I would like to help you but for me to provide you with details, I need to have a bigger picture of your source code. Can you show me your code? You could use pastebin.com to share source code.

Comment: I have pasted the main activity there.

Comment: I am not seeing the part that sets longpress state. Where is "s.setIsLongPressed(true)"?

Comment: " have pasted the main activity there" <-- Where is "there"?

Comment: Could you let me know that if you got the required details ?

Comment: Sure, I saw your code but still, where is "s.setIsLongPressed(true)"?

Comment: I have added that.

Comment: @aab Thanks, I just saw your code and you have done well with `setIsLongPressed`. However, you have to use `getIsLongPressed ` value on `onBindViewHolder ` and make UI changes... In short, you are setting the value, but not using it.

Comment: could you edit above in onBindViewHolder with some code because getIsLongPressed is false inititally and then I set it to true to use that value.

Comment: @aab sure, I have edited my code to provide you with better details.

Comment: I am sorry to ask again but how would I use setIsLongPressed in ClickItem() method. I have made some changes here https://pastebin.com/52nUXjJS. If you could see look at it it would be of great help.

Comment: @aab I have edited my code to provide you with better details. I just saw your code and you only followed up to 2nd procedure that I gave you. You still have to do 3rd and 4th steps to accomplish your desired behavior. (Your job until step 2 looks good)

Comment: I have looked around extensively to check what you said above and followed all steps but the problem remains. notifyDataSetChanged(); and  notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition()); do not highlight the item at all.